# Make WinUI3 TextBox foreground colour persistent between control state changes

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to highlight an error in a WinUI3 `TextBox` by making the text red. However, changes to the control state (e.g. `PointerOver`) remove changes I make to the `Foreground` property, even when using custom states. One complication is that I'd like the text colour to be the default value when not red, so that it is black or white depending on if the app is in dark or light mode.

Is there a way to achieve this without overriding the whole `TextBox` template? I feel like I must be missing something simple.

I've tried remapping the relevant Resource keys to point elsewhere:

```
<TextBox.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForeground" Color="{x:Bind NameTextColour, Mode=OneWay}" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundPointerOver" Color="{x:Bind NameTextColour, Mode=OneWay}" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="{x:Bind NameTextColour, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBox.Resources>
```

But this makes VS produce a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" dialog error (even though `Windows.UI.Color` is not nullable...).

Comment: Use Databinding: you bind TextBox's color to a property like `NameTextColor` and raise INotifyPropertyChanged.OnPropertyChanged on it (on UI thread) when its value changes. That should be enough and "persistent"

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, but binding the `Foreground` property of the `TextBox` doesn't override the colour applied in its `PointerOver` and `Focused` states.

Comment: Directly set `SolidColorBrush` for example `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushKey" Color="#FF000000"/>`. Here `x:Bind` cannot determine an instance of what type object to bind. Or you can write a new style based on `DefaultTextBoxStyle`. See `NumberBoxTextBoxStyle` at `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.4.231115000\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI\Themes\generic.xaml` for an example.

Comment: Thank @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, but directly setting the colour means the colour needs to be static. As you suggest, I will create a new style that edits the `TextBox` template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer this.

You can use the [Control.Foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.control.foreground?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4) Property to specify foreground. The following style only shows the difference to the `DefaultTextBoxStyle` style at `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.4.231115000\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI\Themes\generic.xaml`

```
<TextBox x:Name="nameInput"
         Header="Enter your name:" PlaceholderText="Name"
         Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Red">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            .
            .
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            ...
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                        .
                                        
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            .
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} , TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                        <Storyboard>
                                            .
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                .

                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: My question asked if there was an alternative to overriding the `TextBox` template, but as the answer seems to be no I've marked this as accepted.